# C# xsl transform with imports on WinRT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I'ge got a bunch of xsl transformation files, which are linked using imports like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:import href="another_file.xsl"/>
   <xsl:param name="staticBaseURI" select="''"/>
   <xsl:param name="EDocsReferencedJavascript" select="0"/>
   <xsl:param name="EDocsMode" select="1"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In standard .NET framework you have XslTransform/XslCompiledTransform class which can take a file path, it can handle those imports (because it knows the path and where to find other files) and does a proper transformation. But in windows unversal app (WinRT) this class is not available, the only one I found is XsltProcessor which takes a plain string (not file path) and it can't handle imports.

How to do such transformation in universal app? Is there a way to do it using built in WinRT classes or a free, reliable library for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the only one I found is XsltProcessor which takes a plain string (not file path)

[XsltProcessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.xsl.xsltprocessor.aspx) class you found is for `XsltTransform` in windows universal app.

But it doesn't  take a plain string as you known. The [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.xsl.xsltprocessor.xsltprocessor.aspx) of the `XsltProcessor` class accept a [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.xmldocument) as parameter. For `XmlDocument` object, you can  [load from file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206263), [load from string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206269) and [load from buffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.xmldocument.loadxmlfrombuffer). So you can load file to the `XmlDocument` instance. Which we need pay attention is that windows store app is sandbox structure, not all the files on the device you can visit. More details please reference [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

> it can't handle imports

`XsltProcessor` can handle `<import>` node by a `XmlDocument` object which is load from file. But we need to set the [XmlLoadSettings.ResolveExternals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.xmlloadsettings.resolveexternals) property to true to let the external entity references are to be resolved at the time the document is parsed.

And the sample code like follows:

```
 private async void btnxlsttest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     StorageFile xlstfile =await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/ForImports.xslt"));           
     XmlLoadSettings importsetting = new XmlLoadSettings();
     importsetting.ResolveExternals = true;            
     xsltDoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(xlstfile,importsetting);
     StorageFile xmlfile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/books.xml"));         
     doc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(xmlfile);
     var xsltProcessor = new Windows.Data.Xml.Xsl.XsltProcessor(xsltDoc);
     String transformedStr = xsltProcessor.TransformToString(doc);
     txtshow.Text = transformedStr;        
 }
```

I just put all the test files in `Assets` folder, and the file `ForImports.xslt` contains `import` node like follows. And this sample can load templates from `another_file.xslt`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
<xsl:import href="another_file.xslt"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-imports/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @user3126358, any updates? Have you resolved your issue?